# symfony installation issue with svn

Tags: svn, symfony1

I am trying to install symfony via svn, as per the instruction:

```
Installing from Subversion (recommended)

If you use Subversion, it is even better to use the svn:externals property to embed symfony into your project in the lib/vendor/ directory:

$ svn pe svn:externals lib/vendor/
If everything goes well, this command will run your favorite editor to give you the opportunity to configure the external Subversion sources.
```

so I have my project file inside /var/www/myproject and inside myproject I do have /lib/vendor
when I tried doing svn pe svn:externals lib/vendor/ I am getting the following error:

```
svn: 'lib/vendor' is not a working copy
```

any idea why?

so then I fitured that there isn't a .svn folder in lib/vendor so I tried doing svn add lib/vendor but then it gives me:

```
svn: 'lib' is not a working copy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for Symfony1, [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) stands over [git](http://git-scm.com/) [though you can use [svn for versioning as well](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_svn.html)].